# Prove $k(AB) \leq k(A)k(B)$ where $k(\cdot)$ denotes the condition number

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, condition-number

Given a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and $B$, we need to prove 
$k(AB) \leq k(A)k(B)$ where $k(\cdot)$ denotes the condition number of a matrix.

Is there any thing wrong in the below proof?

$$k(AB)   
= \|AB\| \cdot \|(AB)^{-1}\|
\leq \|A\| \cdot \|B\| \cdot \|B^{-1}\| \cdot \|A^{-1}\|  
=k(A)k(B) .$$

Comment: In the third line, one of the $B^{-1}$ should be $A^{-1}$, otherwise it looks fine. If this is homework you might also be required to show that $\| A B \| \leq \|A \| \|B\|$, unless you did this in your class/lecture.

Comment: If you want the Greek letter $\kappa$ instead of $k$ for the condition number, then use `$\kappa$`.

Comment: As @Oliver pointed out, your reasoning is correct. One important point is to note that *submultiplicative* property of the norm used. When matrices are seen as operators, not all operator norms are submultiplicative. But for *condition number*, usually Euclidean norm is taken and it is submultiplicative.

Comment: Is $\kappa(AB)\leq\kappa(A)\kappa(B)$ still true when $A$ and $B$ are not both invertible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You proof is correct. Both $A, B$ should be invertible, so $\|(AB)^{-1}\|=\|B^{-1}A^{-1}\|\le \|B^{-1}\|\|A^{-1}\| $.

Answer (score 0):

$||(AB)||\leq ||A||||B||$ is not true for a general matrix norm. For example, $||A||=max|a_{i,j}|$ and let $A=B=[1,1;1,1]$.

Comment: usually $\| \cdot \|$ is a submultiplicative norm